# Changing the colour of a specific cell in a go.table?

Tags: python, colors, plotly

A seemingly simple problem, but one I just can't seem to fix,

I have the following code:

```
# Determine the category based on the value of spearman coefficient
coef_category = "Very Low"
if 0.2 <= coef < 0.4:
    coef_category = "Low"
elif 0.4 <= coef < 0.6:
    coef_category = "Medium"
elif 0.6 <= coef < 0.8:
    coef_category = "Strong"
elif coef >= 0.8:
    coef_category = "Very Strong"
# Define a mapping of categories to colors
category_color_map = {
    "Very Low": "red",
    "Low": "orange",
    "Medium": "yellow",
    "Strong": "lightblue",
    "Very Strong": "green",
}

# Determine the significance based on the value of p
significance = "Significant" if p < 0.05 else "Not Significant"

#determine how variable the consensus is for when we consider all the datasets
overall_std_category = "consistent expression"
if overall_std == 0.0:
    overall_std_category = "NA"
elif 0.1 <= overall_std < 0.2:
    overall_std_category = "moderately variable"
elif  overall_std >= 0.2:
    overall_std_category = "highly variable"

# Define a mapping of categories to colors
overall_std_color_map = {
    "NA":"white",
    "consistent expression":"lightgreen",
    "moderately variable":"yellow",
    "highly variable": "red"
}

# Set colors based on the values
#pairwise coefficient
coef_color = category_color_map.get(coef_category, "white")
#overall coefficient
overall_std_color = overall_std_color_map.get(overall_std_category, "white")
#p-value
p_value_color = "lightgreen" if significance == "Significant" else "white"


# Create the figure with the table and set cell colors
fig3 = go.Figure(
    data=[
        go.Table(
            header=dict(
                values=["Correlation group", "Spearman r", "p-value"],
                line=dict(color="white", width=1),
            ),
            cells=dict(
                values=[
                    [
                        "pairwise",
                        "",
                        "consensus",
                        "",
                        "RNA",
                        "",
                        "Protein",
                        "",
                        "RNA-Protein",
                    ],
                    [coef_category,coef,overall_std_category,f'{overall_correlation} ± {overall_std}'],
                    [significance, p],
                    
                ],
                fill=dict(
                    color=[["white"], [coef_color, "white"], [p_value_color, "white"], [overall_std_color, "white"]]
                ),
                line=dict(color="white", width=1),
            ),
            domain=dict(x=[0.6, 1], y=[0, 1]),
        )
    ]
)
```

My goal is to colour the cell which holds the `overall_std_category` by the `overall_study_category_map` . However, It seems that the approach I've taken, of:

`fill=dict(color=[["white"], [coef_color, "white"], [p_value_color, "white"],[overall_std_color, "white"]]`

Which worked for the Other two coloured cells, isn't correctly filling in this value?

For additional clarification:

my table looks something like this:

[image]

The cell which has "highly variable" should ideally be red, as the standard deviation in the cell below is "0.22".

Any help is appreciated as always, and please let me know if I've missed something obvious or necessary :)

Comment: Reading the example in the [reference](https://plotly.com/python/table/#alternating-row-colors), I would think that setting the background color of the cells would need to be specified for the number of columns in a column-by-column list. Since the conditions in your question are complex, you would probably create a list of colors in advance and set them, rather than specifying them in the graph.